# Swift play video in TableviewCell URL from firebase

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, video

I have a tableview which can display images or videos.
When it comes to images I get no problems.

But when it comes to video I'm getting an error on the console which I don't understand.

The error is : "Task .<2> finished with error - code: -999"

From the research I've made it should be exit before execution.
But I really don't understand what it means.

Here's my code for the tableView Cell:

```
var post: Post? {
    didSet {
        updateView()
    }
}
 func updateView() {
    captionLbl.text = post?.caption
    usernameLbl.text = "Test"
    if (post?.isVideo)! {
        if let videoThumbUrlString = post?.videoThumbUrl {
            let videoThumbUrl = URL(string: videoThumbUrlString)
            postImgView.sd_setImage(with: videoThumbUrl)
        }
    }
    if !(post?.isVideo)! {
        if let photoUrlString = post?.photoUrl {
            let photoUrl = URL(string: photoUrlString)
            postImgView.sd_setImage(with: photoUrl)
        }
    }
}
func createPlayer() {
    if (post?.isVideo)! {
        if let videoUrlString = post?.videoUrl, let url = URL(string: videoUrlString) {
            player = AVPlayer(url: url)
            playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
            playerLayer?.frame = self.postImgView.bounds
            playerLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
            self.postImgView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer!)
            player?.play()
            activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
            playBtn.isHidden = true
        }
    }
}
    @IBAction func playBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        createPlayer()
    }
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    playerLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
    player?.pause()
    activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
}
```

When i tap on playButton the video plays but i get the error I've mentioned before.
I'm not sure if is connected but also the activity indicator never stops running.

Hope somebody can help!

Thank you.

---------------------UPDATE
The full console log message is:
"
2017-10-30 14:10:00.996661+0100 PhotoApp[92272:543501] Task .<2> finished with error - code: -999
"

Comment: can u post full log from console?

Comment: @VladPulichev sure i'll put it on my answer... but that's basically all...

Comment: well,  try to put breakpoints to each line of createPlayer() func. I have tableview with photo/video cells. Data is from Firebase too. So, I hope, that I can help

Comment: @VladPulichev if i put the breakpoint i don't get the error message anymore... is it possible that is due to not having the url yet? (like is not downloaded yet)?

Comment: Well, i dont think so. But u can try next code. I'll write answer

Comment: Are u just tapping play button? Are u scrolling your tableView b4 error happens?

Comment: @VladPulichev i'm scrolling before tapping. First row holds an image and the second a video... so i scroll to second row and than tap the play button

Comment: @VladPulichev if i run it on a real device i get this.  CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300, query={
    class = inet;
    "m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
    "r_Attributes" = 1;
    sync = syna;
}

Comment: I think the problem not in the cell.
Try to find solution for this error

Comment: @VladPulichev probably not.... seems to be smt like permission error.... but that's odd... permission are set up correctly...

Comment: I afraid, that I can't help here. Good luck

Comment: @VladPulichev thx for trying! :) i'll try to see if i find something and if i do i'll post it! Thx again!

Answer (score 1):

Well, error does not show something. But try next change:

```
if let videoUrlString = post?.videoUrl, let url = URL(string: videoUrlString) {
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url) // < --
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)) // < --
        playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player) 
        playerLayer?.frame = self.postImgView.bounds
        playerLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        self.postImgView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer!)
        player?.play()
        activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
        playBtn.isHidden = true
    }
```

Comment: I'm new to swift and I'm not sure what actually u have done... but I get no error anymore.... so thanks!! Really appreciate the help! :)

Comment: not true... it does it again... i don't get it... first time i tried it show no error... and the second time...  here it comes again...

Comment: @Marco hmmm. Let me think more
Does it show line of the error?

Comment: Can u unaccept answer? I cant delete it. And I dont want to confuse peoples in the future. If i will have an idea - i post it!